# Conditionally provision a gcp vm instance with terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I would like to condition the provisioning of a resource (gcp vm instance) on a variable, for example:

```
resource "${var.param > 0 ? "google_compute_instance" : "null_resource"}" "cluster" {
  # ...
}
```

but the above is not valid syntax:

```
Error: Invalid resource type name
A name must start with a letter or underscore and may contain only letters, digits, underscores, and dashes.

Error: Invalid string literal
Template sequences are not allowed in this string. To include a literal "$", double it (as "$$") to escape it.
```

Is there a way to accomplish the same? Ideally using terraform alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [count](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/count.html) for that:

```
resource "google_compute_instance" {
  count = var.param > 0 ? 1 : 0
}

resource "cluster" {
  count = var.param > 0 ? 0 : 1
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the side-effect: 
`Because google_compute_instance.[...] has "count" set, its attributes must be accessed on specific instances. 

For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
google_compute_instance.[...][count.index]
`
?

Comment: @Sparkler Sadly there is not, unless you will pre-process your TF file before you apply it. Some ppl use jinja2 to template their TF code to make it "cleaner" later.